# First few lines of jQuery source

Tags: jquery

The first lines of code of the jQuery source ([bit.ly/jqsource](http://bit.ly/jqsource)) are:

```
(function( window, undefined ) {

// Use the correct document accordingly with window argument (sandbox)
var document = window.document,
```

I think I understand what the code does, but not *why* it does it. What is the "sandbox" all about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps prevent people from overriding the main `window.document` or `document`.

Things like this:

```
document = 27;
```

If jQuery called `document.getElementById`, it would fail miserably.

As for `undefined`, its a "hack" to get at the real value of `undefined` because one can do this:

```
undefined = 'haha';
```

then conditions like this would fail.

```
if (myObj == undefined) { 
  alert("don't use myObj"); 
}
```

Comment: What about `window`? Can people do `window = 27` and mess everything up?